# pass texture map to another fragment shader

Tags: webgl, texture2d

I want to generate a texture map in WebGl in one fragment shader and then pass that texture map to another fragment shader for processing but the syntax escapes me. I believe if I understood it correctly, an example I found online said I could do something like this:

```
(1)
// setup frame buffer and depth buffer for the two fragment shaders.


(2)
// texture map generating frag shader:

uniform sampler2D texturemap;

void main(){
    // generate texture map
    vec4 coorindate_value = ...;
    output_texture = texture( texturemap , coorindate_value );
    // my understanding is that that sampler2d will generate some kind of a mapping. how can I map coorindate_value to some other vec4, like another vec4 coordinate???
}


(3)
// second fragment shader:

uniform sampler2D same_texturemap;

void main(){
    vec4 coorindate_value = ...;
    vec4 value = texture2D( same_texturemap , coorindate_value );
    // the returned value should be one of the color values from the first fragment shader, correct??

}
```

I'm not looking for anyone to provide code to help me here necessarily, but just to get some confirmation that I have an understanding of how this could work. **I suppose my main confusion is over what sampler2D actually does. Is it like a dictionary or hashtable in that it maps between two values, and if so, how do I choose what those two values are?**  Any tips or corrections would be great.

thanks much in advance

Comment: `sampler2D` is a reference to a texture. A texture is a 2D array of data you can pull data out of using the `texture2D` function. You pass it the sampler2D uniform and a normalized texture coordinate. Output in WebGL is via a special variable `gl_FragColor`.  You probably need to [read some tutorials on webgl](https://webglfundamentals.org). Here is one [specifically about textures](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html) but if you're not familiar with the rest of WebGL you'll probably need to read the preceding articles.

Answer (score 0):

A `sampler2D` is a reference to a texture unit. A texture unit holds a reference to a texture. A texture is a 2D array of data you can pull data out of using the `texture2D` function. You pass it the sampler2D uniform and a normalized texture coordinate. It returns a *sampled* value from the texture. I say *sampled* value because how that value is generated depends on the filter settings of the texture.

Output in WebGL is via a special variable `gl_FragColor`. The output goes to the current framebuffer to the canvas if no framebuffer is bound.

You probably need to [read some tutorials on webgl](https://webglfundamentals.org). Here is one [specifically about textures](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html) and also [rendering to texture](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html) but if you're not familiar with the rest of WebGL you'll probably need to read the preceding articles.

Comment: ok it seems my understanding of textures and sampler2Ds was correct. do you know how I can fill a texture with data inside one fragment shader ( lets say the fs is just given a texture filled with unimportant initial values ) and then pass that texture to another fragment shader? If not possible I understand. thanks gman.

Comment: fragment shaders output a single pixel at a time. That is all. To decide where that pixel goes you generate positions in your vertex shader. How you do that is 1000% up to you. You could pass in positions via attributes, you generate positions via math, some combination of both. It sounds like you really need to read the tutorials. See: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html

Comment: sure thing, I'll check that out, but once I've filled in data in my texture can I then pass that texture to another fragment shader? if so, how?

Comment: That same way you pass any texture to any fragment shader. It's just a texture. It's not special just because you wrote to it from some other fragment shader. Explaining how to use textures is a giant topic which I why I gave you the links

Comment: I totally understand. Thanks a bunch for the resource.

Comment: gman you said above "Output in WebGL is via a special variable gl_FragColor. The output goes to the current framebuffer to the canvas if no framebuffer is bound." What is the syntax for getting that output from the frame buffer? I want to get that output and input that texture into another fragment shader program but I can't figure out the syntax. I tried just taking the texture from my first fragment shader and applying it to the second with the bindTexture function, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Please read the articles linked. To pass a texture to a shader you declare a uniform sampler, you attach the texture to a texture unit, you then set the shader's uniform sampler to which texture unit you used. To render to a texture you attach it to a framebuffer and bind that framebuffer. All of that is covered in the links at the bottom of the answer. In fact specifically rendering to a texture and then using that texture to render something else is covered in the last link. But WebGL is a big topic. You'll need to read the other articles to understand it.